# How to use ssh with another ssh command and execute echo command

Tags: ssh

How to use ssh with another ssh command and execute echo command

example:

ssh user1@server1 ssh user2@server2 "echo hi >> test/test123"

Its not writing the echo statement to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes will get stripped off as they are passed to ssh, so you need to double your quotes.

You can mix double/single quotes, so I would suggest you try:

`ssh user1@server1 ssh user2@server2 '"echo hi >> test/test123"'`

Alternatively, you can use the first ssh (to server1) to set up a tunnel, then (as a separate command) ssh through the tunnel.